# Enforce explicit function return type annotations?

Tags: typescript

I want to disable the ability to use "any" in typescript. For example, I have the following function

```
func() {
   return true
}
```

i want to require it to be this

```
func(): boolean {
    return true
}
```

I know TSLint can check for this, but I can ignore it and still compile. Is there anyway to require this in order to compile in the TSConfig file?

Comment: Did you tried setting `"noImplicitAny": true` ?

Comment: Actually, neither of these code samples uses the `any` type. The return type is `boolean` in both cases.

Comment: Is tslint an option? You have a no-any option. Alternatively, the tsconfig of `no-implict-any` works good enough for most cases, while still allowing explicit casting to any.

Comment: Related: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typescript-2-3-the-strict-compiler-option

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: "I can ignore it and still compile" is how TypeScript tends to work anyway unless you enable the `--noEmitOnError` config option.  Maybe you should configure your build system so that if tslint fails you don't produce output files.

Answer (score 16):

No, Function return types are inferred in typescript. The compiler itself has no setting to turn off type inference on functions. This feature was requested and decline as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18529#issuecomment-329997774) filed on the typescript repository.

However, your favourite lint tool can warn you when there is no type definition specified for a function. For completeness, I will provide this information.

**tslint** ([deprecated](https://blog.palantir.com/tslint-in-2019-1a144c2317a9))

The rule is called [typedef](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/). Add the following line to your tslint config

```
"typedef": [ true, "call-signature", "arrow-call-signature" ]
```

**typescript-eslint**

The typescript-eslint plugin has this rule called [explicit-function-return-type](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md).

```json
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "error"
  }
```

Comment: Note: `tslint` is now deprecated, `typescript-eslint` should be used instead